# GNU prolog how to get list of list into single list

Tags: list, prolog

So I am having a list of lists [[],[1],[2,3]] and I want to merge this into a single list.

This is was I tried so far I GNU Prolog:

```
function([],[]).
function([Varlist|Vars],Var):-
  function(Varlist,Var1),
  function(Vars,Var2),
  append(Var1,Var2,Var).
```

but this fails when I get the number 1 out, been trying for hours now.

Hope you can help : )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you consider this generalization:

```
function1(L, L).
function1([Varlist|Vars],Var) :-
    function1(Varlist,Var1),
    function1(Vars,Var2),
    append(Var1,Var2,Var).
```

you will see that we get more than required:

```
?- function1([[],[1],[2,3]], R).
R = [[], [1], [2, 3]] ;
R = [[1], [2, 3]] ;
R = [1, [2, 3]] ;
R = [1, 2, 3] ;
false.
```

We should keep just the last solution. Not so easy... Revert to original code:

```
function2([], []).
function2([Varlist|Vars],Var) :-
    ...
```

If we assume Varlist **is** a list, then we will use immediately as argument to append/3 to get Var, and we just recurse to 'flat out' Vars (remaining list of lists)

```
function2([], []).
function2([Varlist|Vars], Var) :-
    function2(Vars, VarTemp1),
    append(Varlist, VarTemp1, Var).
```

Indeed so we solve the problem:

```
?- function2([[],[1],[2,3]], R).
R = [1, 2, 3].
```

but there is a bug, not easy to spot. It turns out that solving it also make the procedure more efficient. See if you can find the bug *and* solve it...

Comment: Found a bit easier way. Not sure if it is as general but it worked for me:
intoList([],[]).
intoList([L|Ls],Vars):-append(L,L2,Vars),f(Ls,L2).